# How to use a Gem in aws with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I want to use gem `httparty` (as an example)

I added a Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'httparty'
```

[image]

My lambda code has:

```
...
require 'httparty'
```

and I call it with

```
response = Net::HTTParty.get('example.com', '/index.html')
```

but the initial `require` is getting

```
{
  "errorMessage": "cannot load such file -- httparty",
  "errorType": "Init<LoadError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'",
    "/var/task/lambda_function.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you run [`bundle install`](https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-install.1.html) to install the gems defined in the Gemfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to bundle non-aws gems into local vendor folder and then zip up those dependencies to be included, i.e.

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle  # <-- Note using path

zip -r function.zip lambda_function.rb vendor/ # <-- vendor/ for the dependencies

aws lambda update-function-code --function-name myFunction \
--zip-file fileb://function.zip --region 'us-east-2' # <= your region
```